# Focus on table cell/column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm using a table for display some text (a table that for each weekday displays several rows of information). The tables always contains information for the current day, so I would like to focus the current day (the column, or at least the `<th>` of the column).

What do I need to achieve it? The `.focus` class is reserved only for input fields right?

(Ps: I'm using bootstrap, if that may help, but I think bootstrap does not have nothing for this)

Edit: If it helps, the website is http://pedrorijo91.github.io/ist-canteen/

Comment: can u give more details? a jsbin or some code snippet would be helpful to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @wrick17 this is the website http://pedrorijo91.github.io/ist-canteen/ 
My goal is to focus on the current day when opening the website in mobile because the table is too big for mobile screens

Comment: so if you are viewing it on your phone, if u go http://pedrorijo91.github.io/ist-canteen/#thursday it will be focused there. if you dynamically add it, you'll get it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the page is loaded and your data is generated just redirect your page to the respective id.

Say for example if it is thursday, get it from your data and just do the following:

```
window.location = '#thursday';
```

this will focus thursday as you wanted.

I have done a bin for it. http://jsbin.com/timozi/1/edit?html,js,output

Just drag the output window to be narrow so that only first 2 or 3 columns are shown and run the code. The seventh column should be highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

You can give focus to a TD element if you previously set tabindex on it.

```
var td = getElementById('someTD');
td.setAttribute('tabindex', 10000);    // or other number
td.focus();
```

Works perfectly, it shows normal focus behavior, so applies focus css rules like:

```
td:focus { background: #E0F8E0; border: 1px dashed red; }
```

Comment: this is the website http://pedrorijo91.github.io/ist-canteen/ 
My goal is to focus on the current day when opening the website in mobile because the table is too big for mobile screens. In mobile is focusing on 19/May with your solution, not sure why

Comment: perhaps there is an error in the way you chose the cell to focus, as anyway it is focusing one, that is not the first

Answer (score 1):

If your intensity hear is to highlight or differentiate current day data with previous data just add extra styles as here for Example..Add class to  tag 
as

```
<tr class="current-day">
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
</tr> 

 .current-day
 {
   background:#006621;
   color:#fff;
 } 

.current-day td
{
   background:#006621;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: No, my goal is to focus the `td` in mobile screens. check my comment on the question @anr-upgraded-version